# "deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds" cordova 3.5.0-0.2.1

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, cordova

I am developing a hybrid app with html5 cordova. I have 3 html pages. I use localStorage and SQLite Plugin. I navigate between those pages. But, when I move from one page to another, cordova features become useless.

my login.html page:

```
        Document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

        function onDeviceReady() {

            var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
                name : "OZEGE",
                bgType : 1 
            });

            //some transactions

        }
        function Login(){
            // my login authorization

        }
```

and after the authorization, I move my other page with this code line;

```
 window.location = "experInfos.html";
```

experInfos.html:`

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
        function onDeviceReady() {
                document.getElementById("devamButonu").disabled = true;


                var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
                    name : "OZEGE",
                    bgType : 1 
                });

                //populate dropdown
                populateMensei(db);
        }
```

`

when the second page opens, console shows;

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. (01:40:11:905)
at www/cordova.js:1154
```

I couldnt populate my drop down list. it shows:

```
SQLitePlugin openargs: {"name":"OZEGE","bgType":1} (02:08:08:610) 
at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.pgsqlite/www/SQLitePlugin.js:8
```

but nothing happens. Why cannot I use device ready on second page ? Because of the config.xml ?

Comment: try this `document.locatiom= "experInfos.html";`

Comment: nothing has changed. I dont think the problem is about the which code changes the page. I guess this has to be about cordova plugins or someth else.

Comment: I have the very same problem and i can't use a single-page approach for that particular project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change the way of navigation. I put all the html files in one page and I just change the visibility of views. It works and there is no problem with this situation now

Answer (score 0):

Something else I found, try adding a sdcard to your emulator

I found my initial error was the file plugin was not being allowed to access a file space, this was because it didn't exist in the emulator, I added an external card to the emulator definition and hey presto it worked

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get navigation to work by concatenating all my stylesheets to a single file, so I'm guessing this has to do with load time or number of file requests etc. in the page you are navigating to. @amenthes I hope that works for you too.